# Differential equations of family of circles

Tags: geometry, ordinary-differential-equations

Find the differential equation of: A family of circles passing through the origin and having centers on the $x-$axis.

I can't figure out the equation of "family of circles passing through the origin and having centers on $x-$axis",please help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The equation of a circle with centre at $(h, k)$ and radius equal to $a$, is $$(x - h)^2 + (y - k)^2 = a^2~.$$

When the circle passes through the origin and centre lies on $x-$axis, then the abscissa will be equal to the radius of the circle and the $y-$co-ordinate of the centre will be zero. i.e., $h = a$ and $k = 0$.

[image]

Then the equation of the circle satisfied the given condition is$$(x - a)^2 + y^2 = a^2\tag1$$

Differentiating both side of $(1)$ with respect to $x$ ,
$$2(x-a)+2yy'=0\implies x-a=-yy'\implies a=x+yy'$$where $~y'\equiv\dfrac{dy}{dx}~$.

Putting the value of $~a~$, in equation $(1)$ ,
$$y^2~y'^2 + y^2 = (x+yy')^2$$
$$\implies y^2~y'^2 + y^2 = x^2+2xyy'+y^2y'^2$$
$$\implies y^2 = x^2+2xyy'$$
which is the required differential equation of the given family of circles.

Answer (score 0):

All circles passing through origin and having centre on $x$−axis, say at $(a,0)$ will have radius equal to $a$.

Then, the general equation of such circles is $$(x-a)^2+y^2=a^2.$$

Comment: But if the centre is at (-a,0) then the equation will be $${(x-a)}^2+y^2=a^2$$,so does the equation contain + and - both value??

Comment: @AnkitaPal, if the centre is at $(-a, 0)$ the equation will be $(x + a)^2 + y^2 = a^2$, which is what you get if you substitute $-a$ into this answer.

Comment: Sorry typing error